# Docker TLS Error on Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am trying to learn about **Docker in ubuntu 15.04**.

When i give any command using docker like "**docker info**", it arise following error:

```
FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I don't understand what does it mean.

Somebody help me to fix this error.Thanks

Comment: Having this same issue. This error is specifically that the docker daemon is not running, but other issues after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using boot2docker and its running, this should solve your problem

eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"

Comment: Thanks i get the solution. @Anup

Answer (score 1):

Is docker running?

```
service docker.io restart
```

Are you running as root?

```
sudo docker info
```

Are the Env variables set?

```
env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://.....:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/.....
```

Comment: I had this in Ubuntu as well, and I think it was either installing as non-root, or running as non-root, and either had to reinstall as root or run as root/sudo or it not running, so I think this answer definitely applies in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue a little bit ago when trying to follow some of the original Ubuntu installation instructions and was unable to start the docker service.

I ran the following to install the latest of docker:

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/gpg |sudo apt-key add -
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu | sudo sh
sudo apt-get update
```

Then after adding my local user to the docker group and rebooting, I still hit the Daemon TLS error.

Investigating the service it appeared to be masked and I tried unmasking it, but it still wouldn't work until I also unmasked docker.socket as well and enabled the service with the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl unmask docker.service
sudo systemctl unmask docker.socket
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
```

Found the answer to the last piece here in case any of you hit this problem as well:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/3Sou7Umo0SA